# How to transform "a.hover" to single click?

Tags: jquery, css, html, responsive-design

I created a responsive website, and works fine in all devices, but the tablet layout has one problem:
The event "a.hover" call a message-box before click, and   the tablet don't use hover effect, it's like a "single-click". So everybody using a tablet need to click 2 times (One for hover and one for click).

I would like transform event "a.hover" in a single click, is possible ?

The solution:

```
    .ads_box:hover{ display:none;}
```

Is not what I expected, but is a solution!

Comment: Is this for styling or functionality? Like does the hover make something only visually change? There are a lot of articles and topics on this and without knowing exactly your use case it's hard to provide a suggestion as to what to do. Just try Googling "hover on mobile" and you'll see lots of options.

Comment: Or you can use JavaScript or jQuery to set a trigger event which will change the CSS properties of the elements you need to change (alternatively, instead of creating dynamic CSS rules, you can script your CSS and then set a JavaScript jQuery event to change the ID or class name. When your ID/class is set to the corresponding CSS, all your style changes will take place).

Comment: Functionality. I was searching for a simple sintaxe, but thanks I'll find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you could find something in the below link.

http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/

Comment: The solution was eliminate all hovers in tablet layout :|

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) to check for device type, and then specify different rules depending on the device (i.e. remove the a:hover for touch devices)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the site to notice when a mobile browser visits it, and change it from a hover menu to a click-to-drop down. I honestly have no other solution other than that, but it's worked fine for me.

P.S. (I've been coding swift recently, so I'm a bit rusty in my web development languages, but I think I can live with forgetting needles web jargon ;) )

P.P.S Or you could just permanently change to to a click-to drop down menu. I don't really think tilt bother your users too much.